# Basic graphic elements in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I´m confused about the basic graphic elements of PhoneGap. If PhoneGap uses HTML, JavaScript and CSS, then the graphic elements of PhoneGap will be the graphic elements of HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

I have been trying to find the graphic elements of PhoneGap, but I haven´t had luck.

Can somebody give me a little insight?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by graphic elements? I'm sure you can use svg elements in phonegap as well, basiaclly any graphic element that can be displayed by the browser can be used in phonegap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PhoneGap, as in Cordova, the programming model is Web. You need to put your HTML, JS and CSS in the `www` folder as if you were creating a standard web page.

For instance, Cordova creates a basic index.html file with a hello world sample that uses JavaScript to detect the readiness of the application in the device (the event is called "deviceready") and formats the UI using CSS. Look at the code in this repo

https://github.com/apache/cordova-app-hello-world/tree/master/www

Hope this helps